# Why does the winding number become zero when the region is unbounded

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis

I know "mathematically" that the winding number is zero when the region is unbounded because
$$\lim_{a\to\infty}\left|\frac1{2\pi i}\int_\gamma\frac{\mathrm dz}{z-a}\right|=0$$

However what I don't unserstand is: if the winding number is just

> an integer representing the total number of times that curve travels counterclockwise around the point

Why does this even depend on whether region is bounded or not?  I mean why is the number of times a curve travels counterclockwise around the point is zero when a region is unbounded.

Comment: If $\gamma$ is a fixed (and bounded) curve, then when $a$ gets far enough away it will be seen in roughly the same direction from all points on $\gamma$,

Comment: @Troposphere, but the definition says the winding number is zero of any point is zero. not just far away points.

Comment: As $a$ moves around, the winding number can only _change_ when $a$ crosses the curve. So if $a$ is in the unbounded (path-connectedness) component of $\mathbb C\setminus \gamma$ it means that you can _move_ it to be so far away that the winding number around it is obviously zero -- and since the winding number stays constant during that movement, it must have been zero to begin with.

Comment: Take $\gamma(t)=e^{it}$ ($t\in[0,2\pi]$). Consider the point $a=1+i$. How many times does $\gamma$ go around $a$? Answer: $0$. And this holds for *any* $a$ with $|a|>1$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos, but the diffiention says that the winding number is zero for all points . But in your example for $a=0$ the winding number is non-zero.

Comment: If you move a point outside the circle the obvsouly the winding number is zero that doesn't mean it is zero inside the circle. I still don't get it.

Comment: The unit circle divides the plane into two regions, a bounded one and an unbounded one. The example that I have provided ($1+i$) belongs to the unbounded one and the winding number is $0$ in this case. You have provided an example from the *bounded* region. And then it turns out that the winding number is $1$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos, So basically when we say that the winding number is zero in unbounded region we mean the winding number outside the curve is zero. is this correct?

Comment: It's $0$ on the *unbounded* connected region outside the curve.

Comment: Once $\gamma$ is fixed, the winding number is a function of $a$. Like many functions, different inputs can give different outputs. If your input value $a$ is in the unbounded connected region of $\gamma$ then the winding number is $0$. But if your input value $a$ is in one of the bounded connected regions of $\gamma$, the winding number could well be nonzero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you formulate it, your question "Why does the winding number become zero when the region is unbounded" does not make much sense. The path integral
$$\frac1{2\pi i}\int_\gamma\frac{\mathrm dz}{z-a}$$
is defined for any closed curve $\gamma : [r,s] \to \mathbb C$ such that $a$ is not contained in the image of $\gamma$. You do not need any region. And in fact the value of this integral is a number in $\mathbb Z$ (which definitely depends on the point $a$). Thus the statement
$$\lim_{a\to\infty}\left|\frac1{2\pi i}\int_\gamma\frac{\mathrm dz}{z-a}\right| = 0$$
makes sense for any closed curve. For the limit the absolute value is irrelevant, it has the same meaning as
$$\lim_{a\to\infty}\frac1{2\pi i}\int_\gamma\frac{\mathrm dz}{z-a}\ = 0 .$$
In other words, we have to show
$$I(a) = \int_\gamma\frac{\mathrm dz}{z-a} = \int_r^s\frac{\gamma'(t)}{\gamma(t)-a}dt = 0$$
for $\lvert a \rvert > R$.

The image of $\gamma$ is contained in an open disk with center $0$ and sufficiently large radius $R$. Let $\bar \gamma(t) = \gamma(t) - a$. Then
$$I(a) = \int_r^s \frac{\bar \gamma'(t)}{\bar\gamma(t)}dt.$$
If $\lvert a \rvert > R$, then the image of $\bar \gamma$ is contained in an open disk $D$ with center $a$ and radius $R$. This disk does not contain $0$, thus there exists a branch $\ln$ of the complex logarithm on $D$. We get
$$I(a) = \int_r^s \ln'(\bar\gamma(t))dt = \ln(\bar\gamma(s)) - \ln(\bar\gamma(r)) = 0 . $$

*Remark:*

The above result implies that the winding number of $\gamma$ is $0$ on the unbounded component of $\mathbb C \setminus \gamma([r,s])$. Note that there is exactly one unbounded component; it contains all points with absolute value $> R$.